# Android menuItem act strange?

Tags: menuitem

I belive my question is kinda simple for most experienced Android developers but not for me!

I am trying to set the name in a menuItem and make the text WHITE colored. First of all the text gets displayed only if I klick on the menuItem, or rather when I click on the menuItem the text turns white and is readable. What I dont know is if the text gets displayed only when I click on the menuItem or if it for some reason changes color to WHITE when clicked so I am able to see it? Any useful help how I can make the text white and visible all the time in the menuItem?

item.setTitle(this.task.getName()); is supposed to be White and visible all the time in the menuItem!. Thx alot!

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate( R.menu.show_task_feedback_menu, menu );
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch ( item.getItemId() )
    {
    case R.id.show_task_feedback_menu_add_feedback:  item.setTitle(this.task.getName()); <------------- Here is the problem!!!!!!!!!!
    this.startTaskFeedback();
    return true;
    default: return true;
    }
}
```